# Program runs unpredictably with the exact same input values

Tags: java, if-statement, output

I'm new to programming and java and have an assignment that I've been able to run properly- sometimes, but it is inconsistent. I ran it with certain values once and then directly tried re-running it with the same exact input as before. The next time or so it doesn't work. Please help point me to how to fix this unreliability. I can't find any reasons for this in my code. Please help.

```
import java.util.*; 
public class Calculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) { //void
        boolean done = false;
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (!done){
            displayMenu();
            String selection = getUsersSelection(console);
            done = processSelection(selection, console);
            //caluculateResults(console);
        }
        System.out.println("Thank you for using this program");
    }

    private static boolean processSelection(String selection, Scanner console) {
        boolean done = false;
        if (!selection.equalsIgnoreCase("Q")){
            if (selection.equalsIgnoreCase("U")){
                caluculateResults(console);
                }
            else if (selection.equalsIgnoreCase("H")){

            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Incorrect entry...try again!");
            }
        }
        else {
            done = true;
        }
        return done;
    }

    private static void caluculateResults(Scanner console) {
        displayCalculatorInstructions();
        double operand1 = console.nextDouble();
        char operator = console.next().charAt(0);
        double operand2 = console.nextDouble();
        double result = 0.00; //double from int
        boolean isOperatorValid = true;
        if (operator == '+'){
            result = operand1 + operand2;
        }
        else if (operator == '-'){
            result = operand1 - operand2; 
}
        else if (operator == '*'){
            result = (double) operand1 * (double) operand2;
        }
        else if (operator == '/'){
            if (operand2 != 0.00){
                result = operand1 / operand2;
            }
            else {
                result = (int)Double.NaN;
            }
        }
        else if (operator == '^'){
            result = Math.pow(operand1, operand2);
        }
        else {
            isOperatorValid = false;
            System.out.println("Invalid operator");
}
        if (isOperatorValid){
            System.out.println("The result of your operation is: ");
            System.out.printf(operand1 +" "+operator+" "+operand2+" = %5.3f", result); 
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    private static void displayCalculatorInstructions() {
        System.out.println("Enter a mathematical expression to evaluate");
        System.out.println("Valid operations are: +, -, /, *, ^ for power");
        System.out.println("Expression are entered with spaces between the values and operator");
        System.out.println("Here is the valid format:");
        System.out.println("\t<value><space><operator><space><value>");
        System.out.print("Your expression: ");
    }


    private static String 
    private static void displayMenu() {
        System.out.println("Enter one these options:");
        System.out.println("\tH for Help");
        System.out.println("\tU for using calculator");
        System.out.println("\tQ for exiting this program");
        System.out.print("Your selection: ");getUsersSelection(Scanner console) {
        String selection = console.next();
return selection;
    }

    }

}
```

Comment: `fix this unreliability` ... I doubt that you are really seeing this behavior.  Are you certain that the same exact input was entered in both cases?

Comment: I have ran your code and its working fine. Can you tell me the input for which you are getting unreliable answer?

Comment: So strange how output result varies. My input for example was 12.2 ^ 3. The first time the output was 1815.848 and the second time I received the invalid input warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am confident the supplied code above won’t compile without a few changes. And I feel confident you are getting bad input somewhere because I never got different results from your `caluculateResults` method.

Main problem in is in your supplied displayMenu method below

```
private static String 
private static void displayMenu() {
    System.out.println("Enter one these options:");
    System.out.println("\tH for Help");
    System.out.println("\tU for using calculator");
    System.out.println("\tQ for exiting this program");
    System.out.print("Your selection: ");getUsersSelection(Scanner console) {
    String selection = console.next();
  return selection;
}

}
```

This has a couple of problems… first the compiler would warn about the missing “;” `after  private static String`. Then the line `System.out.print("Your selection: ");getUsersSelection(Scanner console) {` doesn’t look right at all. It appears you are trying to select the user input? Then get it? Lastly for this method, it appears you want to return a string variable called `selection` however the method does not have a signature to return a String and also in the main method, you are not capturing it if it did. In this case I will assume you want to return the String.
Below are the changes I made to this method.

```
private static String displayMenu(Scanner console)
{
  System.out.println("Enter one these options:");
  System.out.println("\tH for Help");
  System.out.println("\tU for using calculator");
  System.out.println("\tQ for exiting this program")
  System.out.print("Your selection: ");
  String selection = console.next();
  return selection;
}
```

In your main method…

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    boolean done = false;
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (!done){
        displayMenu();
        String selection = getUsersSelection(console);
        done = processSelection(selection, console);
        //caluculateResults(console);
    }
    System.out.println("Thank you for using this program");
}
```

Minor changes are needed in main. First, displayMenu() is supposed to return a string, which you do not capture. Since you were not capturing it you are basically asking the user to input again, because displayMenu() just asked the user for input, but you didn’t get it. So let’s get the users input from displayMenu() since we are returning the string now with `String selection = displayMenu(console);` then simply remove the line `String selection = getUsersSelection(console);` this is where I think you are getting bad input, because your method calculateResults never gave different results in my tests.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  boolean done = false;
  Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
  while (!done)
  {
    String selection = displayMenu(console);
    done = processSelection(selection, console);
    System.out.println("");
  }
  System.out.println("Thank you for using this program");
}
```

Hope this helps.